# Is there any way to customise promise.all?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

As per the current behavior, The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason for the first promise that rejects.

For example:

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

Currently, I was trying to implement a **polyfill** something similar to `promise.all` (Like, `promise.sequenceAll`) where the result of the 1st promise will be fed to the next promise.

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.sequenceAll([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Expected output: The result of promise1 will be passed to the promise2 as an argument. If any of the promises rejects, then it will execute `promise.catch();`

Comment: Sounds like you need something like RamdaJS (https://ramdajs.com/). "[Ramda] makes it very easy to build functions as sequences of simpler functions, each of which transforms the data and passes it along to the next. Ramda is designed to support this style of coding". Do you have a more specific scenario on how you will use result of promise1 inside promise2?

Comment: I want to create a polyfill for this. I could not use any third-party library.

Comment: `The result of promise1 will be passed to the promise2 as an argument.` An argument of _what_? `promise2` is not a function!

Comment: Yes, in this case, promise2 is not a function, so it will skip it and will pass the same arguments to promise3. Basically, it should have a (typeof name === 'function' ) check.

Comment: @SaswatArabinda `promise3` is not a function...

Comment: I was trying to write something new. that's why I gave this example. Basically, I want to create Promise.sequenceAll polyfill where the result of the 1st promise will be used in the evaluation of the second promise and so on.

Comment: Your example does not clarify how you intend to use the 1st promise in the evaluation of the second promise and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this and return the resolved value of the first promise from a `.then()` handler which will make it become the resolved value of the resulting promise:

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(([v1]) => {
   // make the resolved value of the first promise be the resolved value
   // of the subsequent promise
   return v1;
}).then((value) => {
   // v1 is now the resolved value of the chain
   console.log(value);
});
```

You could encapsulate that behavior in your own function is you wanted, though it's pretty easy to just add a `.then()` handler onto an existing `Promise.all()` when you want this behavior.

Comment: By default promise.all will have single then method. So you can't chain it. How to achieve that?

Comment: @SaswatArabinda - I don't know what that comment means.  You can do `Promise.all().then(...).then(...).then(...)`.  Each `.then()` returns a new promise which can do anything any normal promise can.  The return value of a previous `.then()` becomes the resolved value of the next `.then()` in the chain.  That's how promises chain.  `Promise.all()` just returns a normal promise that chains like all of them.  The only different with `Promise.all()` is that it's resolved value is an array of values (which you can manually do with any promise).

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response

Comment: @SaswatArabinda - If this answers your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn your some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to do that

Comment: @SaswatArabinda - Not the up arrow.  Click the checkmark - anyone who asks a question and gets an answer can do that.